# Put strings in arrays shopify liquid

Tags: arrays, if-statement, shopify, liquid

In shopify there are products with metafields, which contain multiple numbers. These numbers represent the fishing zones of the fish that is inside the product.
For example, for product A the value is simply '27' and for product B the value is '27/48'. My way to go would be to create an array and put in values inside of this array.
Something like this:
If the metafield contains 27, then put 'Atlantic Ocean' inside of the array. If the metafield contains 48, then put 'Pacific Ocean' inside of the array. At the end I would print out the array.
Is this a good way to go or is there a better one?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm just assuming that saving "Atlantic Ocean" etc. in the Metafield as an array is not an option for you. So here's how I would approach this:

Create a global metafield that contains all definitions like so:

```json
{
  "27": "Atlantic Ocean",
  "48": "Pacific Ocean"
}
```

Then, in liquid:

```
{%- liquid
  assign definitions = shop.metafields.namespace.key.value
  assign parts = product.metafields.namespace_key.key.value | split: '/'

  for part in parts
    echo definitions[part]

    unless forloop.index == parts.size
      echo ', '
    endunless
  endfor
-%}
```

This would render for product A:

```
Atlantic Ocean
```

And for product B:

```
Atlantic Ocean, Pacific Ocean
```

This way you can easily update the definition JSON when you want to add a new type of ocean without updating the liquid source code.